# Target size (torch.Size([800])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([800, 4]))

Tags: python, pytorch

```
# Fit the multi-class model to the data
torch.manual_seed(42)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(42)

# Set number of epochs
epochs = 100

# Put the data to the target device
X_blob_train, y_blob_train = X_blob_train.to(device), y_blob_train.to(device)
X_blob_test, y_blob_test = X_blob_test.to(device), y_blob_test.to(device)

# Loop through data
for epoch in range(epochs):
  ### Training 
  model_4.train()

  y_logits = model_4(X_blob_train)
  y_pred = torch.softmax(y_logits, dim = 1).argmax(dim = 1)

  print(y_logits.shape, y_blob_train.shape)
  loss = loss_fn(y_logits, y_blob_train) # <<- ValueError

  acc = accuracy_fn(y_true = y_blob_train,
                    y_pred = y_pred)
  
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

  ###  Testing
  model_4.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
    test_logits = model_4(X_blob_test)
    test_preds = torch.softmax(test_logits, dim = 1).argmax(dim = 1)

    test_loss = loss_fn(test_logits, y_blob_test)
    test_acc = accuracy_fn(y_true=y_blob_test,
                           y_pred = test_preds)
    
  # Print out whats happening
  if epoch % 10 == 0:
    print(f'Epoch: {epochs} | Loss: {loss:.4f}, Acc: {acc:.2f}% | Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}, Test    acc: {test_acc:.2f}%')]
```

I have tried using squeeze() in y_logits, but the issue still remains(In training, line: loss = loss_fn(y_logits, y_blob_train)). What is the reason for this error and how can I solve?

Comment: What happens with `loss = loss_fn(y_logits, y_blob_train.argmax(-1))`? Also what is the loss function?

Comment: y_logits has the size of ([800, 4]) and  y_blob_train ([800]), some kind of shape problem that doesn't match. Also despite not adding y_logit.squeeze() in the tutorial I am following(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_ikDlimN6A&list=WL&ab_channel=DanielBourke  , timestamp: 13:32), I tried using the function and it's not working. The loss fucntion I am using is CrossEntropy loss

Comment: The fact is that the loss fn expects both to have shape `[800, 4]`. Are the `y_blob_train` integer class indices?

Comment: So, I finally figured it out. I wrote `loss_dn` instead of `loss_fn` and later referred to `loss_fn`. As the loss function helps to convert the shape of y_logits to match with y_blob_train, the error kept popping up. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured it out. I wrote `loss_dn` instead of `loss_fn` and later referred to `loss_fn`. As the loss function helps to convert the shape of y_logits to match with y_blob_train, the error kept popping up. Thank you for the help